# I can't click buttons in Firefox when I edit the <body> of a page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When I use Firefox developer tools to edit the body of a webpage, the page buttons either disappear or stop functioning like in the example below. This does not happen in Chrome and all the buttons work fine as they suppose to.
here are the steps that lead to the problem:

I go to the webpage that I need to work with, then I need to edit a few things in the page so I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open the dev tools, right click on `<body>` then *Edit As HTML* and change what I need to change and apply it and it works just fine with Chrome but in Firefox and other browsers the buttons stops working or disappear.

Here's the [link to the example page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick). (This is only an example not the real page I'm working with, because the real one is in Arabic and requires more steps.)

[image: Two screenshots of the results section of an online code editor. The first screenshot shows a line of text with a 'Click me' button below it. In the second one, labeled 'After edit', both the text and the button are gone.]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a link to the website and the exact steps you do to get the error.

Comment: What's actually the reason you want to edit the whole page's HTML output within the browser? On the next page reload the changes are gone again, anyway. You still need to make those changes in the server-side script to save them permanently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Firefox DevTools obviously do the same as when you copy the outer HTML and then execute this

```
document.body.outerHTML = `*copied HTML*`;
```

inside the DevTools' console.

That's why all the event handlers as well as iframe contents are gone after you finish editing the HTML, e.g. in this case you can't edit the code at the left side and there is no output shown at the right anymore.

The Chrome DevTools seem to do something smarter here and recognize what has changed and only update those parts when you save the HTML. Therefore the output on the example page is still visible afterwards and the code can still be edited.

I've [filed an enhancement request for that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1383613), so the behavior in this case can get improved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so are you saying there is nothing I can do to fix this?

Comment: Well, instead of editing the whole `<body>` you can edit the inner elements that don't contain the iframe or the element structure inside of the iframe. Or you could fix the bug I just reported. :-) [The DevTools code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools) is also just JavaScript.

Comment: @AbdulHameedAl-Ibadi, & Sebastian, I don't consider this to be a bug in Firefox (a request for enhancement, at best). AbdulHameed edited the `<body>` in HTML. Firefox did exactly what it was told to do: It changed the HTML of that element. It's debatable as to which of either the way Chrome does it or the way Firefox does is the "correct" way. The way Chrome does it assumes you don't know what you're doing. The way Firefox does it, it's doing exactly what you told it to do. Personally, unless I've set an option that it's supposed to make assumptions, I'd prefer that it does what I tell it to.

Comment: @Makyen Right, it's an enhancement request (Bugzilla just calls all of them "bugs"). And yes, the behavior of the Firefox DevTools is exactly reflecting the user action. Non-the-less it may be surprising for developers when their event listeners or iframe contents disappear after editing an element.

Comment: @SebastianZartner, Understood & agreed. OTOH, it'd be surprising to other developers when editing the HTML did *not* remove listeners, etc., which might be the entire reason for the edit. The issue is more that the user's expectations need to be set to match what is going to happen by their action, not that the tool should guess those expectations. A better solution is to both inform the user what's going to happen & give them the option as to which will happen. Arguably, the UI already provides this ability by allowing the user to choose to edit a smaller portion of the HTML/edit nodes.

Comment: In addition, there is an argument which would argue that auto-magically not applying the effects of changing the specified HTML just perpetuates the lack of understanding that changing the HTML (e.g. `.innerHTML`) will impact on the rest of the page. How often do we see questions with problems resulting from people naïvely assigning to `.innerHTML`, or it's equivalent, without regard for the side effects? Should the browser's native tools reinforce that misconception?

Comment: A browser's developer tools should primarily provide a good UI and UX for debugging websites. It's not their goal to align their functionality to simple DOM APIs. APIs like `.innerHTML` are surely often misunderstood, but that's what documentations should explain and isn't something that should limit developer tools' functionality. But that discussion is out of the scope of the question here and may rather be discussed in the enhancement request linked above. OTOH, I'm still wondering what's @AbdulHameedAl-Ibadi's use case to edit the whole `<body>` element in the browser instead of an IDE.

Comment: @SebastianZartner I'm sorry I can't say why I need it in public but if you want to know I can pm the details to you or something I don't mind.

Comment: Understanding your actual use case would have been good to provide you with alternative answers. Generally, editing the whole HTML structure within the browser seems unnecessary to me.